# Problems with reshape in GAN's discriminator (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I was trying to implement various GANs in Tensorflow (after doing it successfully in PyTorch), and I am having some problems while coding the discriminator part.

The code of the discriminator (very similar to the MNIST CNN tutorial) is:

```
def discriminator(x):
    """Compute discriminator score for a batch of input images.

    Inputs:
    - x: TensorFlow Tensor of flattened input images, shape [batch_size, 784]

    Returns:
    TensorFlow Tensor with shape [batch_size, 1], containing the score 
    for an image being real for each input image.
    """
    with tf.variable_scope("discriminator"):
        x = tf.reshape(x, [tf.shape(x)[0], 28, 28, 1])
        h_1 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5))
        m_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(h_1, 2, 2)
        h_2 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.conv2d(m_1, 64, 5))
        m_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(h_2, 2, 2)
        m_2 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(m_2)
        h_3 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.dense(m_2, 4*4*64))   
        logits = tf.layers.dense(h_3, 1)
        return logits
```

while the code for the generator (architecture of InfoGAN paper) is:

```
def generator(z):
    """Generate images from a random noise vector.

    Inputs:
    - z: TensorFlow Tensor of random noise with shape [batch_size, noise_dim]

    Returns:
    TensorFlow Tensor of generated images, with shape [batch_size, 784].
    """
    with tf.variable_scope("generator"):
        batch_size = tf.shape(z)[0]
        fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.dense(z, 1024))
        bn_1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc)
        fc_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.dense(bn_1, 7*7*128))
        bn_2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc_2)
        bn_2 = tf.reshape(bn_2, [batch_size, 7, 7, 128])
        c_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose(bn_2, 64, 4, 2, padding='valid'))
        bn_3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(c_1)
        c_2 = tf.tanh(tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d_transpose(bn_3, 1, 4, 2, padding='valid'))
```

So far, so good. The number of parameters is correct (checked it). However, I am having some problems in the next block of code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# number of images for each batch
batch_size = 128
# our noise dimension
noise_dim = 96

# placeholder for images from the training dataset
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
# random noise fed into our generator
z = sample_noise(batch_size, noise_dim)
# generated images
G_sample = generator(z)

with tf.variable_scope("") as scope:
    #scale images to be -1 to 1
    logits_real = discriminator(preprocess_img(x))
    # Re-use discriminator weights on new inputs
    scope.reuse_variables()
    logits_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

# Get the list of variables for the discriminator and generator
D_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'discriminator')
G_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'generator') 

# get our solver
D_solver, G_solver = get_solvers()

# get our loss
D_loss, G_loss = gan_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)

# setup training steps
D_train_step = D_solver.minimize(D_loss, var_list=D_vars)
G_train_step = G_solver.minimize(G_loss, var_list=G_vars)
D_extra_step = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, 'discriminator')
G_extra_step = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, 'generator')
```

The problem I am getting is where I am doing the reshape in the discriminator, and the error says:

```
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Sure, the value for the batch_size is None (btw, the same error I am getting even where I am changing it to some number), but shape function (as far as I understand) should get the dynamic shape, not the static one. I think that I am a bit lost here.

For what is worth, I am giving here the link to the entire notebook I am working: https://github.com/TheRevanchist/GANs/blob/master/GANs-TensorFlow.ipynb if someone wants to look at it.

NB: The code here is part of the Stanford CS231n assignment. I have no affiliation with Stanford though, so it isn't homework cheating (proof: the course is finished months ago).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator seems to be the problem. The output size should match the discriminator. And the other issues are batch norm should be applied before the activation unit. I have modified the code:

```
    with tf.variable_scope("generator"):

        fc = tf.layers.dense(z, 4*4*128)
        bn_1 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc))
        bn_1 = tf.reshape(bn_1, [-1, 4, 4, 128])

        c_1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(bn_1, 64, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        bn_2 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(c_1))

        c_2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(bn_2, 32, 5, strides=2, padding='same')
        bn_3 = leaky_relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(c_2))
        c_3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(bn_3, 1, 5, strides=2, padding='same')

        c_3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(c_3)
        c_3 = tf.image.resize_images(c_3, (28, 28))
        c_3 = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(c_3)
        c_3 = tf.tanh(c_3)
        return c_3
```

Your code gives the below output when run with the above changes

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing `None` to reshape you must pass -1.

So this:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [tf.shape(x)[0], 28, 28, 1])
```

becomes

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

and this:

```
bn_2 = tf.reshape(bn_2, [batch_size, 7, 7, 128])
```

becomes:

```
bn_2 = tf.reshape(bn_2, [-1, 7, 7, 128])
```

It will infer the batch size from the rest of the shape you provided.

Comment: Already tried it, but it doesn't change anything. The same error remains.

Comment: @TheRevanchist Can you provide the whole stacktrace? If those two are the only appearances of reshape, changing those Nones to -1 should have solved the problem.

Comment: The generator function is not returning anything. Also the generator output size (34x34) is different from the discriminator input size (32x32). Make the changes in generator by modifying the layers or apply a image rescale at the end.

Comment: @vijaym I don't think generator has to output something. It takes a tensor as input noise, and gradient descent will adjust that noise into something.

Comment: @Mihail The discriminator needs real inputs and fake inputs. The fake inputs should come from the generator.

Comment: @viljay m - That's right. It works now. If you can post your comment on a new answer, I could credit that as the right solution.

On a side note, it seems that I got stucked into the dark arts of gans. The discriminator is learning much faster, and its cost function reaches near to 0, which means that the generator is generating just dark images.

It is weird, cause it is working the right way in the PyTorch version I wrote (using the exact same architecture).